# PHP Parse time Days/hours/minutes + round up to closest step

Tags: php

I Have system, where people ar tracking there spent time on project.
After project is ending, I want to count there spent time + round up to closest step

For now, I have function, that only convert time to readable format

```
function parse_time($t, $k="",$step){
    if($t == 0){
        if($k == ""){
            return $t;
        }
        return $k;
    } else {
        if($t >= 3600){
            $h=floor($t/3600);
            $a=$t%3600;

            if($a >= 60){
                $m=round($a/60);
            } else {
                $m=0;
            }
        } else{
            $h=0;
            $m=round($t/60);
        }

        $d=($d > 0)?$d."d":"";
        $h=($h > 0)?$h."h":"";
        $m=($m > 0)?$m."min":"";

        $t=$d.$h.$m;

        return $t;
    }
}
```

I want to add parameter to function step ( in minutes ), So

> If the  step = 5 parsed time 41h 20min output 41h 25min
>
> If the  step = 15 parsed time 41h 20min output 41h 30min
>
> If the  step = 20 parsed time 41h 20min output 41h 20min
>
> If the  step = 30 parsed time 41h 20min output 41h 30min
>
> If the  step = 60 parsed time 41h 20min output 42h 0min
>
> If the  step = 180 parsed time 41h 20min output 42h 0min
>
> If the  step = 0 parsed time 41h 20min output 41h 20min

What would be best solution to do that? Thank you :)

Comment: You are basically asking us to either design, or design and write code from a Specification. 
That is not what StackOverflow is for, we help each other fix code related issues we are having, we dont write code for you

Comment: You get me wrong, I am hoping to someone point me in right direction. Thank you :)

Comment: Its not completely clear what you want, cant you just multiply minutes with the steps?

Comment: @ElvisLoksts : Do you want to round up time intervals to the next half hour, hour and so on?
What is unclear: what does the input data look like. It's not clear from your function code. Are strings like '41h 20min' given or a time in seconds?

Comment: @jspit I have different scenarios where steps might be different. Time given in function is in seconds. Steps I want to add in minutes, for simple use.
I want to round up spent time by given step.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to convert all times and intervals to seconds and then work with modulo (%).

First of all, I'll give you two useful help functions.

```
function strTimeToSeconds(string $time): int {
  return strtotime('1970-01-01 '.$time.' UTC');
}

function secondsToHuman(int $seconds):string {
  $hours = (int)($seconds/3600);
  $seconds -= $hours * 3600;
  return $hours.':'.gmdate('i:s',$seconds);
}
```

A example.
Given are 148800 seconds (=41hours 20min).

```
$seconds = 148800;
$interval = strTimeToSeconds('15 minutes');  //900 Sec
```

Round up to closest interval:

```
$seconds = $seconds - $seconds%$interval + $interval;  //149400
```

To convert seconds to hours, minutes and seconds we now use secondsToHuman().

```
echo secondsToHuman($seconds);  //41:30:00
```

Comment: Thank you a lot :)
I will try after weekend to make it all work, and post here results.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @jspit

Works as expected :)

```
function step($a, $b) {
if ($a == 0){$seconds = 0;} else {$seconds = $a-1;}
if ($b == 0){$step = 0;} else {$step = $b*60;}
$seconds = $seconds - $seconds%$step + $step;
return $seconds;
}
echo secondsToHuman(step(3900, 5));
```